# What's the purpose of Akka extension?

Tags: scala, akka

Can someone tell me the purpose of Akka extension?
Even after reading [the document](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/extending-akka.html), I have no idea when to use Akka extension.

Answer (score 2):

An extension is like a singleton but bound to the actor system lifecycle, rather than the JVM, this means it will not leak between actor systems in test for example, which a global singleton would.

A common and easy to understand use case is to parse configuration into a more application specific, type safe structure of your own classes rather than to access the configuration by key directly from the config api.

Quite a bit of the built in Akka tools are actually extensions just like acjay mentions.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a way of creating plugins that extend the core functionality of Akka. You would use it when you want to create a general-purpose library that might be applied across many Akka projects. Much of the Akka distribution is implemented as extensions. As you begin to use nontrivial feature in Akka, you'll undoubtedly find that you at least consume the extension pattern to get access to run-time data/instances for using extensions.

One example is [distributed publish and subscribe](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/distributed-pub-sub.html) for Akka Cluster. Every node within the cluster that wants to participate in the pub/sub must have exactly one `mediator` running, which is responsible for distributing messages across the cluster. So `mediator` is a local singleton. The framework manages the singleton for the application by initializing it and storing it in its extension instance, which is retrieved by applying it to the actor system.